# "Из страны, исповедующей мусульманство", - можно?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> Забыла спросить, как имя моего нового не – знакомца, но спешу записать
>   какие-то подробности разговора с неким симпатичным представителем
>   негроидной расы лет двадцати пяти. **Из страны, исповедующей
>   мусульманство**.

Как лучше отобразить НЕ ЗНАКОМЦА?

Тире без отбивок?

Слитно, но отрицание прописным? курсивом?

Через дефис?

В скобках - (не)знакомца?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оригинально смотрится вариант с тире: *Забыла спросить, как имя моего нового не – знакомца*... По-цветаевски почти).

Из страны, исповедующей ислам.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Исповедовать ислам** – правильное название, но официальное (по стилю не очень подходит). **Исповедовать мусульманство** – неофициальное название, **единого мнения о его правильности нет**, но в словарях допускается, и стилистически смотрится лучше.

**МУСУЛЬМАНСТВО**, -а; ср. Одна из наиболее распространённых религий мира, последователями которой являются мусульмане; ислам. **Исповедовать м.**

**ИСЛАМ**, -а; м. [араб. islām – покорность] Одна из мировых религий, основанная на семи догматах: вере в единого Бога - Аллаха, в ангелов, в книги Божьи, посланников Аллаха, в конец света, предопределение, воскресение мёртвых; **мусульманство.** Идеи ислама. Проповедь ислама.

https://kratkoe.com/islam-i-musulmanstvo-v-chem-raznitsa/

2) **Забыла спросить, как имя моего нового *не – знакомца*...**

Желательно дополнительно выделить курсивом, чтобы подчеркнуть особое значение и написание слова.